When using pytest-bdd how do I define a dataset should be operated on by a scenario?
I am familiar with behave in which I can define data for a step like so:

Feature: My feature

  Scenario: My scenario
    Given some data
      | order_nr | customer_name | delivery_date |
      | 1        | John Doe      | 2023-10-01    |
      | 2        | Jane Smith    | 2023-10-02    |


The table is available to the Python step code as the “.table” attribute in the Context variable passed into each step function. The table for the example above could be accessed like so:

@given('a set of specific users')
def step_impl(context):
    for row in context.table:
        model.add_user(name=row['name'], department=row['department'])

behave tutorial > Step Data

I like having the data visible to the person reading the feature file however I'm using pytest-bdd. I would like to achieve the same using pytest-bdd.
pytest-bdd however does not have the equivalent of the Context variable therefore I don't know how to achieve this. Is there a way to pass data from the feature file to a step definition when using pytest-bdd?

Looks like support for datatables got added 18 days ago https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-bdd/pull/712
Just have to wait for pytest-bdd 8.x to get released. Hopefully won't be long.
